# HTML5 datalist not working in Firefox 6.0.2

Tags: html, firefox, html-datalist

Though, most online resources on HTML5 mention that datalists are supported in Firefox 4 & above, but it does not work with my Firefox 6.0.2.

Also tried the example at http://www.html5tutorial.info/html5-datalist.php.
Does it work only in Firefox 4?
Is there a way to check the support with Modernizr?

Regards,
S

Comment: I use Firefox 7.0.1 and the above example works. Maybe it´s a problem on your side...

Comment: Should work fine in Firefox 6.  Did you try safe mode?

Comment: Datalist worked with Safe Mode. And then I disabled the Google Toolbar, it worked in regular mode. Thanx Boris Zbarsky.